# Do I need to configure SQL*Plus for SSL?

Tags: oracle, ssl, amazon-rds

I am a total noob when it comes to Oracle databases, so please bear with me.
I have the task to configure an AWS RDS-based Oracle database for SSL connection. However, the [documentation states that I have to configure SQL*Plus in order to achieve that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.Options.SSL.html#Appendix.Oracle.Options.SSL.ClientConfiguration). I am uncertain, if this is really required, because as per my understanding SQL*Plus is kind of Database connectivity tool such as SQLDeveloper and nothing from the Database itself. Is this correct?

Thanks for clarification in advance

Answer (score 0):

SQL Plus is a Database utility tool so as the documentation states its required, a database without utilities is like a computer without a mouse and keyboard or like a builder without his tools you can't work on a project if you haven't got ya tools,

so yes you need SQL Plus or an alternative database tool that works with Oracle based databases/centers

Comment: Ok, but that means that I do not have to configure sth. on the database server itself, right? SQL*Plus is a client tool such as SQLDeveloper, correct?